# ClassCastException when need to parse httpServeletRequest

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

I run my code from tomcat but getting error

```
HashMap<String, Object> params;
params = (HashMap) HttpUtils.getParamsFromRequest(request);
```

HttpUtils code below

```
    public static Map<String, ? extends Object> getParamsFromRequest(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
    return httpServletRequest.getParameterMap();
}
```

but getting exception like this

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.catalina.util.ParameterMap cannot be cast to java.util.HashMap
at se.mindspot.tender.backend.servlet.service.file.FileServiceServlet.doGet(FileServiceServlet.java:47)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Comment: getParamsFromRequest() returns ParameterMap not hashmap. Change params to ParameterMap instead of hashmap.

Comment: I think ParameterMap inherit Map class so it will not be a problem.

Comment: You can simply use Map instead of HashMap

Comment: Either changing params to Map or ParameterMap  will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Map` is an interface, `HashMap` is a concrete implementation. [`ParameterMap`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/util/ParameterMap.html) implements `Map` but **does not** sub-class `HashMap` so it cannot be *cast* to a `HashMap`. The proper thing to do is usually

```
Map<String, Object> params;
params = HttpUtils.getParamsFromRequest(request);
```

and [program to the `Map` interface](https://stackoverflow.com/q/383947/2970947). However, you can do

```
params = new HashMap<>(HttpUtils.getParamsFromRequest(request));
```

if you **need** a `HashMap` and have some other kind of `Map`, but that involves a copy.